# Junit good practices: Do I test for runtime error condition?

Tags: java, exception, junit

Let's say I have a code that does some DB work and has a happy path and the only unhappy flow, that only occurs when DB connection is down, like this:

```
  public Report createReport(
      String reportType, Report reportData, ReportUser reportUser, Timestamp createTs) {
    KeyHolder reportIdHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    try {
      saveReportDetails(reportType, reportData, reportUser, createTs);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) { <-------------- This extends RuntimeException 
      log.error(
          "DataAccessException while trying to insert report with name {}",
          reportData.getReportName(),
          e);
      throw e;
    }
    ...
    // More of the happy path code here
  }
```

I've got a test for the happy path, but is it a good practice to test for the Runtime exception flow as well?

The app is a SpringBoot Rest app, so it doesn't die when the exception is rethrown after logging.

Comment: Yes, you should test happy path and others as well if you can.

Comment: Even if it the failure was caused by a non-recoverable error? I know, that doesn't apply in this case, but in principle?

Comment: Yes, you should test for errors, whether recoverable or non-recoverable.

Comment: Your object needs to tell users that there's been a non-recoverable error.  What do you expect them to do if there is?  Your test should prove that you've held up your end of the contract.